# Why does "git log --tags=<pattern>" add "refs/tags" to the output?

Tags: git

I am using `git log --source --tag=<pattern>` to limit the output to certain tags and display those tags.  It qualifies the displayed tags with `refs/tags/` but it doesn't do this for `--tag` without a pattern (or if I don't specify `--tag` at all).

Why is this, and is it possible to turn it off?

```
$ git init
Initialised empty Git repository in /tmp/repo/.git/
$ touch new-file
$ git add new-file
$ git commit -m "Added new file new-file"
[master (root-commit) c151765] Added new file new-file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 new-file
$ git tag TEST-TAG
$ git log --oneline --source --tags
c151765 TEST-TAG Added new file new-file
$ git log --oneline --source --tags=*
c151765 refs/tags/TEST-TAG Added new file new-file
```

(I have observed this on git 1.9.1 and 2.1.0.)

Comment: `| sed 's=\trefs/tags/=\t='`

Comment: Thanks @choroba :)  I've already modified my program to cope but this seems weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Side note: `--source` adds the "source" reference from which some commit was first reached, to the `git log` output.)

> [Sometimes the tags are fully-qualified.]  Why is this, and is it possible to turn it off?

All of Git's references share one big name-space.  Except for the special cases (`HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, and so on) they all live under the top level directory<sup>1</sup> `refs/`.  The next level determines the *type* of the reference: `refs/heads/` contains branch names, `refs/remotes/` contains remote-tracking branches, and `refs/tags/` contains tags.  (There is also `refs/notes/` for notes, and `refs/stash`, which is just a file rather than a directory, for `git stash`.)

When using `--branches=<pattern>`, `--glob=<pattern>`, `--remotes=<pattern>`, or `--tags=<pattern>`, you wind up seeing the full names.  In a way, it's more interesting to see that this *doesn't* happen when using `--tags` (or `--branches` or `--remotes`; there's no equivalent for `--glob`).  The reason, though, is that [it's an implementation quirk](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6fe1b1407ed91823daa5d487abe457ff37463349/revision.c#L2066-L2090).  If you examine the linked code, you will see that the `--tags=` variant (at the bottom of the highlighted section) passes an explicit `refs/tags/` to `for_each_glob_ref_in`, while the `--tags` variant (at the top) does not.

There are actually two source files with the same code pattern.  The quirk is, I think, actually much clearer in [`builtin/rev-parse.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/rev-parse.c#L708-L718), but `git log`'s annotations are due to the code in `revision.c`.

Since it is hard-coded in the source, the answer is no, you can't turn it off, you can only modify it after the fact.

Note that if you use `--source --branches --tags`, and you have branch and tag names that match<sup>2</sup>—such as `refs/heads/blergh` and `refs/tags/blergh`—and you see:

```
f0b2db2 blergh do something or other
```

you cannot tell if `blergh` is a branch name, or a tag name.

---

<sup>1</sup>When the references are *packed*, i.e., stored in `.git/packed-refs`, this "directory" notion is just conceptual, but originally, and still today when the references are unpacked, this really is a directory: if you peek into your `.git` directory, you will find `refs/` which contains `refs/heads/` and so on.

<sup>2</sup>This is a bad idea in general.  It all works according to the rules, but the rules can be confusing.  In particular, [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) says the tag comes first, and it does with most Git commands (such as [`git show`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html)), but [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) disagrees and will check out the branch, not the tag (which actually makes sense: to check out the tag, you can write `refs/tags/blergh` but doing `git checkout refs/heads/blergh` gets you a detached HEAD).  If you find you have done this—made a branch and tag with the same name—by accident, un-do it. :-)